# Finding example of quasi isomorphism that has no quasi inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Between differential graded algebra $V,W$, a chain map $f\colon V\to W$ induces homomorphism between its homology. If this becomes an isomorphism between the homology of $V,W$, call this quasi isomorphism. My goal is to find quasi isomorphism such that there is no quasi inverse, i.e. chain map $g\colon W\to V$ that induces isomorphism on their homologies.
There is an easy example using the following chain complexes

$A :0\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\to0$ (map given by multiplication by $2$)

$B : 0 \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0$

I can give a chain map from $A$ to $B$, the obvious one, which induces isomorphism on the homology so is an quasi isomorphism. But there is no such map from $B$ to $A$ since $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ has torsion.  and I can give algebra structure here, though stupid structure it is (e.g. defining everything to be zero), but it works. So there exists counterexample.

But I want to find counterexample using vector spaces, and it is harder than general algebra (allowing any $R$-module). Would somebody help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any complex of vector spaces $A$ whose homology is bounded above is colocal with respect to acyclic complexes.  This essentially means that quasi-isomorphisms out of $A$ all have quasi-inverses.  Similarly if $B$ has bounded below homology then it's local and quasi-isomorphisms into $B$ have quasi-inverses.  So one reason you may be having a hard time is that at a minimum you're going to need to look at complexes that have unbounded homology.

Comment: @Jim Can you explain what local and colocal means in this context or give reference.

Comment: Colocal means that any map into an acyclic complex is null homotopic.  This is a much higher level than maybe you and/or the OP wanted, but if $A$ is colocal and $B$ is a complex then the quotient functor from the homotopy category to the derived category induces an isomorphism on homs from $A$ to $B$.  Quasi-isomorphisms are actually isomorphisms in the derived category so this would mean that there's a quasi-inverse map in the homotopy category, hence a quasi-inverse chain map.  For a ref see "hoprojective resolutions" in Murfets notes: http://therisingsea.org/notes/DerivedCategories.pdf

Comment: Turns out looking at unbounded complexes isn't enough, see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

There are no examples in the category of vector spaces, for an elementary proof of this argue that any complex
$$\cdots \to A_i \to A_{i + 1} \to \cdots$$
is quasi-isomorphic (with quasi-inverse) to the complex
$$\cdots \to H^i(A_\bullet) \overset{0}{\to} H^{i + 1}(A_\bullet) \to \cdots$$
This is done in two steps, first argue that every complex can be written in the form
$$\cdots \to I_i \oplus K_i \oplus I_{i + 1} \to I_{i + 1} \oplus K_{i + 1} \oplus I_{i + 2} \to \cdots$$
where the map sends $I_{i + 1}$ to itself and kills $I_i$ and $K_i$.  Next write down the obvious chain maps to and from the complex
$$\cdots \to K_i \overset{0}{\to} K_{i + 1} \to \cdots$$
and check that they are indeed quasi-inverse to each other.

Comment: This is true iff our category semisimple (for modules ring has to be semisimple) It's equivalent to the fact $K(Mod_R)$ is equivalent to $D(Mod_R)$. This means that you should be able to find example for any ring witch is not semisimple and $\mathbb Z$ is the simpliest.

Comment: Dear Jim, Isn't the OP's question about DGA's, rather than just comlexes of vector spaces? Regards,

Comment: @MattE: At the end the OP specifically asks for a counterexample using vector spaces.

Comment: Maybe you're asking why complexes of vector spaces are relevant to DG modules?  You can think of any ring as a DG algebra concentrated in degree zero.  The DG modules are then exactly the chain complexes.

Comment: Dear Jim, I interpreted the OP's question as asking for an example of a quasi-isomorphism of DG algebras over a field (hence the terms in the complex underlying the DG algebra are vector spaces) which doesn't admit a quasi-inverse.  But perhaps I misunderstood.  Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more technological argument, using model categories.

Give the category of bounded chain complexes over a field the projective model structure. Every chain complex is fibrant, and since we're over a field, they are all cofibrant (i.e. free). The "Whitehead theorem" for model categories gives what you want: a weak equivalence (i.e. a quasi-iso) between any pair of complexes is a homotopy equivalence.